# Vertically scaling ElastiCache Redis cluster via CFN

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

As per cloudFormation [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html#cfn-elasticache-replicationgroup-cachenodetype), changing `CacheNodeType` for an ElastiCache cluster requires *[No interruption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html#update-no-interrupt)*. I went through ElastiCache vertical scaling [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/redis-cluster-vertical-scaling.html), however I still have few questions.

If a change the `CacheNodeType` via CFN for an ElastiCache cluster which is currently serving traffic,

1. Does it create a new cluster(end-point) or update nodes in existing cluster?
2. Will it continue to serve traffic during the migration?
3. What happens to existing data in cache. Are they migrated to new nodes in background while the live traffic is being served with minimal impact on parameters like hit-rate.

Looking for a documentation which clearly explains the vertical scaling process for ElatiCache redis in cluster mode with replicas.

Comment: Why not just create a dummy cluster, and check what actually happens?

Comment: This should answer your questions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Scaling.RedisStandalone.ScaleUp.html